# Scala convert Array of string to List of Integers

Tags: scala

How to convert array of string to list of integers using val. I am using below code to do this

```
object ArraytoListobj {
  def main(args :Array[String]) {
    val intList :List[Int] =  args.toList
    println(intList)
  } 
}
```

When trying to compile the programme, I am getting below error.

```
  scala:3:  error: type mismatch;
  found   : List[String]
  required: List[Int]
  val intList :List[Int] =  args.toList
one error found
```

Comment: `args.map(_.toInt).toList` but it will throw if any `String` contains non-digit characters.

Comment: Thanks @ jwvh it solved my problem

Answer (score 7):

You can just do that, if you are sure all the element in the args are going to be Int.

```
val strToInt = args.map(_.toInt).toList
println(strToInt)
```

Comment: I would love to improve my answer, if the person who downvoted let me know the problem.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I guess this misses the fact that there may be strings in the array which are not parseable to an `Int`.

Comment: I explicitly mentioned that if you are sure that all the elements are Int so i don’t think that should be the reason

Answer (score 6):

### Edit:

As of Scala 2.13.0, you can write:

```
val listOfInts: List[Int] = args.flatMap(_.toIntOption)
```

---

### For Scala < 2.13

If you want to convert and discard any non `Int` matching Strings:

```
val listOfInts: List[Int] = args.flatMap(i => Try(i.toInt).toOption).toList
```

Comment: Thanq @ Yuval. I will try to implement this

Comment: in Scala 2.13 (which is still in milestones), you will be able to cut `Try` out of it and just `args.flatMap(_.toIntOption)`